# How to use the package logpap?

Tags: grids

Please help (or provide) me a real example for the package logpap. I have searched the web and found no real latex example or no real manual either for this package.

I have guessed something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{logpap}
\begin{document}
\put(0,91){\loglinpap(8mm,8mm)(1,1){1}{0}}
\end{document}
```

but it did not work nicely !!

Well, I would like to be able to generate loglog a4papers with 1x1, 2x1, 3x1, 2x2, 3x2, 3x3 logarithmic decades of a loglog paper. I teach some experimental physics course and these papers are used a lot by the students.

Comment: "no real manual" Well, https://ctan.org/pkg/logpap has some examples...

Comment: Ah I see you have already read that. Well, `\put` is supposed to be a part of TikZ, so... first start with learning TikZ I guess...

Comment: Correction, `\put` is a part of `picture` package.

Comment: @user202729 picture is a not a package, it is a core latex environment.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, an incomplete answer, but perhaps a step forward.

Looking here https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/logpap/ is a place to obtain the relvant 4 files:

[image]

Having a look into the Readme says:

```
Copyright (c) 2004 Mike Kaufmann
mike.kaufmann@ei.fh-giessen.de
Licence: LPPL

1. What is it?
The logpap package provides four macros for drawing logarithmic-logarithmic,
logarithmic-linear, linear-logarithmic and (because it was easy to implement)
linear-linear graph paper with LaTeX.

2. Example
Look at the file example.pdf to get an overview.
The source can be generated by answering the question "There is an example
file in logpap.dtx. Generate it? [y/n]" with y when running lcd.ins thru TeX.

3. Generating logpap.sty
Simply run:    tex logpap.ins

4. Making the Documentation
To get contents, cross references and index right, run TeX and makeindex
as follows:

latex logpap.dtx
latex logpap.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist logpap.idx
makeindex -o logpap.gls -s gglo.ist logpap.glo
latex logpap.dtx

5. Files
00readme    example.pdf    logpap.dtx    logpap.ins
```

So my preliminary understanding is, that it is intended to be run from the command line or from a terminal, see "2. Example". (To me the description reamins too cryptic, but some Tex-Guru here will certainly be able to open our eyes - again.)

Finally the .dtx file contains lots of stuff, including some kind of Latex document environment. The Readme suggests, that somehow the users keyboard entries (Y/N) will finally create "what you wanted" ... However, the .dtx doesn't tell me so, at least not at a quick glance.

Kindly notice, how said file ends.

```
 % \iffalse meta-comment
%
% Package logpap
% Copyright (c) 2004 Mike Kaufmann, all rights reserved
%
% This program is provided under the terms of the
% LaTeX Project Public License distributed from CTAN
% archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt.
%
% Author: Mike Kaufmann
%         Mike.Kaufmann@ei.fh-giessen.de
% \fi
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
% \CheckSum{1968}
%
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
%<*package>
\def\fileversion{0.6}
\def\filedate{2004/02/01}
%</package>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{logpap}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
%\OnlyDescription
\begin{document}
   \DocInput{logpap.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%
%<*package>
% \fi
%
% \DoNotIndex{\,,\ }

% ... yada yada yada ...

\put(85, 4){\makebox(0,0)[cl]{\texttt{\bs DefineLPLabelDist\lb 0.5mm\rb}}}
\DefineLPThickTickLen{2mm}\DefineLPMedTickLen{1mm}\DefineLPLabelDist{1mm}
\end{picture}
\caption{Overview}\label{fig:ov}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%</example>
```

Comment: there is not need to unpack anything. The example.tex is in the doc folder of the texmf-dist.

Comment: Yes it is, and it doesn't tell much, what to do, see comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the **Some Examples for the logpap package** (file example.pdf)

> The `logpap` package provides four macros for drawing
> logarithmic-logarithmic, logarithmic- linear, linear-logarithmic and
> (because it was easy to implement) linear-linear graph paper with
> LATEX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{logpap}

\begin{document}
    \loglinpap(80mm,10mm)(1,1){1}{0}[X-name][Y-name]
    
    \vspace{3cm}


    \LPSet{notext,  nofsnx}
    \DefineLPMinLineDist{1.9999mm}
        
    \loglinpap(80mm,10mm)(1,1){1}{0}[X-name][Y-name]
        
    \vspace{3cm}
    
    \DefineLPThickTickLen{1mm}
    \DefineLPMedTickLen{0.5mm}
    \DefineLPLabelDist{0.5mm}
    
    \loglinpap(80mm,10mm)(1,1){1}{0}[X-name][Y-name]        
        
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

To generate the documentation download the complete package from [logpap.zip](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/logpap.zip)

Extract the file `logpap.dtx` and from the command line, from the same directory,  run `pdflatex logpap.dtx`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 3x3 on A4-size paper:

[image: 3x3]

I've labelled the command parameters for ease of use via information in the error messages text.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{logpap}

\voffset-2cm
\hoffset-0.5cm
\textheight25cm
\textwidth14cm

\parindent0pt
\parskip1ex plus.3ex minus.2ex
\pagestyle{empty}
\unitlength1mm

\newcommand*{\lp}{\textsf{logpap}}
\newcommand*{\bs}{\char '134 }
\newcommand*{\lb}{\char '173 }
\newcommand*{\rb}{\char '175 }
\newcommand*{\param}[1]{\texttt{\textit{#1}}}



\newcommand\picwidth{140} % in units
\newcommand\picheight{250} % in units
\newcommand\xdecades{3} % 1-9
\newcommand\ydecades{3} % 1-9
\newcommand\xstartvalue{1} %
\newcommand\ystartvalue{1} %
%%{The format of the start value is:\MessageBreak
%% optional + or -, followed by 1-3 digits, optionaly\MessageBreak
%% followed by one of the letters [yzafpnumkMGTPEZY].
%%Log axis start value:
%%                 Only -100, -10, -1, 1, 10 and 100 are allowed.

\begin{document}

\vspace{2mm}
\begin{picture}(\picwidth,\picheight)
\LPSet{nofsnx,notwoninex,notwoniney}
\put(0,0){\loglogpap(\textwidth,\textheight)(\xdecades,\ydecades){\xstartvalue}{\ystartvalue}[X][Y]}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While people like you keep appearing I will continue having hope in humanity.